# Unable to use Code data type in Mongoose Schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I wanted to store a data type of `Code` in my MongoDB database per the [docs](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_datatype.htm).
The issue is that when I use Mongoose to specify this type, I get an error:

`ReferenceError: Code is not defined`

And yes, Mongoose's [doc's](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#type-key) don't have a type of `Code`.

Say I want to save Javascript code in my MongoDB database, how could I do so?

For more insight into why I am doing this: I want to save Puppeteer scripts in the database, and using the FS module add them to a file, execute them and send the results as a response object back to the client.

Right now, the code is saved as `String`, which seems to cause execution errors.

For more information, please don't hesitate to ask.

Thank you,

Comment: This might help with your use case https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server. To combine with `mongoose` -> https://github.com/mongoosejs/mongoose-function

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-to-js ??? "Make plain text (HTML, CSS, JSON, etc) require()-able." Maybe you want to try this package